# Warn me when binding to an undefined value

Tags: angularjs

Is there a devmode setting to `console.warn` me when defining an angular binding to something `undefined`?

This would be helpful to catch typos and API changes during development, and could then be turned off in production.

**Example:**

JS:

```
$scope.user = {firstName:'Sam', lastName:null};
```

HTML

```
First: <input ng-model="user.first_name"/> <!-- broken -->
Last: <input ng-model="user.lastName"/> <!-- good -->
```

Ideally, Angular could notify that `user.first_name` resolves to `undefined` and warn me, while `user.lastName` resolves to `null`, so is all right.

Comment: No. Also, what if a property is supposed to be `undefined` by design? That's the job for unit tests. if the problem applies to ng-model, you can add a decorator for ng-model directive to specifically catch undefined bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish it with the help of `Proxy`. I demonstrated only the starting point example. So you can create base controller with *"proxy"* logic at constructor(and apply it only at case of development stage) and then inherit all other controllers from it:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var handler = (function() {
    var arrUndef = [];
    return {
      get: function(target, name) {
        if (
          target[name] === undefined 
          &&
          arrUndef.indexOf(name) == -1 
          && 
          ['document', 'children', 'and other'].indexOf(name) == -1
        ) {
          arrUndef.push(name);
          console.log(`Warning: ${name} is undefined!`);
        }
        return target[name];
      }
    };
  })();
  $scope.__proto__ = new Proxy($scope.__proto__, handler);

  $scope.existed = 33;
  $scope.anotherexisted = 55;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='existed' />
  <input type='text' ng-model='absent' />
  <p>{{notexisted}}</p>
  <p>{{anotherexisted}}</p>
</div>
```